# Constructing an $\epsilon$-net for a Lipschitz subspace of $L^2$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, sp.spectral-theory, global-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Let $X$ be a subset of $L^2([0,1])$ which contains only Lipschitz function.
Also, the member of $X$ are uniformly bounded
$$
|x(t)| < M, \text{ for all $x \in X$ and $t \in [0,1]$}.
$$
Let $F: X \to [a,b]$ be a bounded Lipschitz functional
$$
|F(x) - F(x')| \le \| x - x' \|, \text{ for all } x \in X.
$$
The minimum of $F$ can be approximate
by forming a finite $\epsilon$-net $D_m=\{x_i\}_{i=0}^m$ of $X$, and then taking
$$
\min \left\{F(x_i)  : x_i \in D_m \right\}  , \tag{1}
$$
as an approximation to $\min\left\{  F(x) : x \in X \right\}$.

What is a good way to construct the $\epsilon$-net $D_m$?

Since the function in $X$ are Lipschitz, I would use truncated Fourier series of order $n$ to build $D_m$.
Is it then true that for any $x \in X$, there is an $x_i \in D_m$ for which
$$
\|x - x_i \| \le \frac1n? \tag{2}
$$ 
Or is (2) delivered only by using truncated Chebyshev polynomial of order $n$?

Are there other good choices for building $D_m$ than trigonometric polynomial?

My greatest fear is that $X$ is not compact. 
So that no $\epsilon$-net can gives (1).
Is this fear justified?
From the different assumptions, I think it can be dispelled, but I don't see the proof.

Comment: A uniformly bounded set of Lipschitz functions is totally bounded even in $C[0,1]$ by Ascoli-Arzela.

Comment: For your question about (2), see for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series#Uniform_convergence

Comment: @ Bill Johnson: the statement is that each $x\in X$ is Lipschitz, but unless I misunderstood something we have no control on the Lipschitz constants uniformly in $x$ so Ascoli doesn't apply. @Nicolas': your assumption $|x|\leq M$ is ambiguous: do you mean mean $|x(t)|\leq M$ uniformly in $t\in (0,1)$ and $x\in X$, or rather $|x|_{L^2}\leq M$ (in which case Ascoli fails)? From what I see I rather recommend Rellich-Kondrachov ($X\subset H^1\subset\subset L^2$) or Riesz-Frechet-Kolmogorov, but in any case you need a uniform bound on the Lipschitz constants!

Comment: @leomonsaingeon It's true that a uniform bound on the Lipschitz constant is needed. I think I can get one. I clarified the assumption $|x| \le M$, I meant $|x(t)| \le M$. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ok, then if you can get uniform Lipschitz bounds Ascoli works as suggested by @BillJohnson and you relative compactness of $X$ in the $L^{\infty}$ topology. But this still doesn't help to construct the best posisble $\epsilon$-net, sorry...

Comment: If you do not impose a bound on the Lipschitz constant, $X$ may fail to be relatively compact ; its $L^2$ - closure could be the whole closed ball of radius $M$ of $L^\infty$. Possible remedy: Find a smaller domain which is compact but where $F$ has the same infimum. Or  use a weaker topology that makes $X$ compact and $F$ lower semicontinuous.